# Shortcut for resource location in Intellij

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea

In eclipse we have `alt+enter` to get the resource location in our folder path in system. What is the equivalent shortcut in `Intellij`. I don't see it in the list of shortcuts [Jetbrains Shortcuts](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/migrating-from-eclipse-to-intellij-idea.html)

Answer (score 0):

In IDEA you could select the element and press:

- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to get the **relative** element path
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to get the **absolute** element path

After that the path will be copied to the clipboard and you could paste it using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> shortcut.

Comment: I tried it, nothing is happening, I am using Intellij IDEA community edition.

Comment: Please read clarification, it works both in Ultimate and Community editions.